# AJAX/PHP simple code fails to work

Tags: php, ajax

I was following a tutorial to understand how AJAX/PHP works but i'm having an issue.

Let me start with the code.

escalationTest.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name.." /> <br>
<input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Enter Name.." />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="post();" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function post()
{

    var name= $('#name').val(); 
    var age= $('#age').val();

    $.post('escalation.php',{postname:name,postage:age},
    function(data)
    {
            $('#result').html(data);

    });
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

escalation.php:

```
<?php

echo "working";

?>
```

I've typed the code exactly how its in the tut. From its output when i click the submit button i should "working" in the result div which is not happening.

What am i doing wrong here..?

Thanks.

Comment: That code uses jQuery, which you have not included on the page.

Comment: crap! i can't believe i forgot that, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Download a version of jQuery and then link to it with this script tag.

While you can link to an online version, it's not ideal for eventual production use and you should definitely get a local copy.

Answer (score 1):

add the folowing line to your head tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple fix - you're missing jQuery. Add the following:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your head element.